# What creatures are optimized for delivering messages?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

We are looking for small creatures that can serve as frequent messengers between PCs and their factions or sponsors during an adventure. Consider owls like in Harry Potter which seemed to be able to travel farther than regular birds and could also always find exactly the person to whom they were delivering.

Traits that would optimize a creature for delivering messages include:

- **Speed/Translocation**: The greater the speed, the better the creature. Owls in Potter seemed to travel virtually any distance. Gates? Teleport? Skills with either might be ideal.
- **Discernment**: The more that the creature can find its intended recipient - the better the creature. Like dogs trained on the scent of a shirt.
- **Non-sentient** (or only mildly so): The more a creature is a commodity that everyone can use (rather than a precious sentient being) the better.
- **Discreetness**: The smaller the messenger the better so it can get through small windows or doors unobstrusively, quietly or invisibly to reach the PCs each day (i.e. think of Dobby the house elf)
- **Two Way Communication**: A great messenger would be one that can return with a message as well.

If a matching creature doesn’t exist, using the “skinning” guidelines would be acceptable (similar to how Constructs in adventures are often listed as “use stats for X”) rather than making up a new creature.

**In sum, what is/are the best creatures with a constellation of talents that could be “skinned” to serve as effective in-game messengers (akin to Potter’s owl)?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74728/discussion-on-question-by-praxiteles-what-are-magical-creatures-optimized-for-de).

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs on RPG.se at all. Remember that [this site is for *only* "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) And as previously established, you aren't qualified nor approved as CCC adventure submitters — required *before* writing begins — and this one is explicitly against CCC rules. I fail to see the utility to *us* as a community in entertaining further questions on this Quixotic quest.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie These are games who at their heart are often *all* about Quixotic quests. Would that we were all on one. If any community was the right one for these type of quests, *this* would be it.

Comment: I agree, this community is great, go ahead and ask in [chat] for more ideas, but as a question on the mainsite, I agree with what SSD says...

Comment: I vote to reopen. What is our RPG if it cannot reproduce creatures as iconic as Hedwig? The question is practical and answerable - whether people are writing CCC adventures or not.  See the great answers by @Philboncer and DuckTapeAl that right now are trapped in chat.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yes, any reference to CCC seems to throw the discussion into a rat hole. (See chat confusion and SSD’s Quioxotic comment.) Skinning is a standard method used by WoTC across multiple adventures (i.e. see DDAL06-02 The Redemption of Kelvan’s constructs and TOA clay warriors.) If feels fair to restrict a question to answers that fit the very practices of WoTC whether or not they work for CCC adventures.

Comment: Based on clarification of your circumstances I'm reopening.

Comment: @Praxiteles Please don't confuse a site about RPGs as being like RPGs. Being about RPGs doesn't relax our rules an iota; Quixotic quests for impossible dreams are still within our "don't ask" rules.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ha...understood

Comment: @Praxiteles We've… actually had problems with that at least once before. Thanks for understanding. :)

Answer (score 2):

What distances are we talking about? A skeleton, per *Animate Dead* has a move of 30', but is immune to exhaustion, which means that while traveling, it can Dash with every action, and run 24 hours a day. This allows a skeleton to deliver a message up to 144 miles away in one day. These could be maybe reskinned as the skeletons of small animals.

The magic item *Sending Stones* allows for one Message sent per day; perhaps those could be reskinned as messenger animals.

Ethereal travel is fast, at least in some worlds; maybe use cute little baby Phase Spiders.

The Homonculous maintains a psychic link to its creator, who can perceive all it does, but it cannot speak. Maybe a homonculous with a little chalkboard travels with the party.

Answer (score 1):

### Reskin *sending*, and make it look like a Kirit.

The CCC rules don't mention spells directly, but the idea of reskinning without changing mechanics appears frequently in the CCC texts. With that in mind, I'd suggest reskinning the existing *sending* spell. It meets all of your requirements: it's a short, textual message, it doesn't rely on a sentient messenger, it's undetectable through normal means, and it's instantaneous, regardless of distance.

What I'd suggest is that, on some schedule you dictate, a Bedine contact of the players casts a custom version of *sending* that requires a Kirit as a focus. When cast, this version of the spell sends the Kirit to the party instantly, where they can receive the message and send one back

Comment: Interesting! That also prompts the idea of reskinning Sending Stones as Construct birds so then they could operate once a day. (i.e. Turn the constructs into the “Kirit” birds to which we referred in our question before we edited the question to clarify it)